# Why do you divide the raw data by 16?

Tags: math, hex, imp, squirrel

http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf

Read page 3, Operation – Measuring Temperature.  The following code works to get the temp.  I understand all of it except why they divide the number by 16.

```
local raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
    local SignBit = raw & 0x8000;  // test most significant bit
    if (SignBit) {raw = (raw ^ 0xffff) + 1;} // negative, 2's compliment

    local celsius = raw / 16.0;
    if (SignBit) {celsius *= -1;}
```

I’ve got another situation http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Pressure/MPL3115A2.pdf Page 23, section 7.1.3, temperature data.  It’s only twelve bits, so the above code works for it also (just change the left shift to 4 instead of 8), but again, the /16 is required for the final result.   I don’t get where that is coming from.

Comment: @NathanHughes does that really matter in this problem?

Comment: Look at Table 1 in the data sheet you linked to - the temperatures have a resolution of 0.0625 degrees C, e.g. 07D0h = 125 degrees C.

Comment: And as a bonus, tagging with the relevant language enables syntax highlighting, thereby making the code more readable.

Comment: I added it for you guys.

Comment: @Nakilon I wish I knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw temperature data is in units of sixteenths of a degree, so the value must be divided by 16 in order to convert it to degrees.